# How to search a sentence or some words in that sentence in indexed data using solr

Tags: solr

Suppose I have a sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and it may or may not contain some special characters. I have an indexed data which contains lists such as {fox, over, etc..}. So when I search with the sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" in the indexed data it might have to give a hit. The sentence containing that words must be highlighted too.

Comment: Exactly what is your search query, and what is the indexed text? If you've indexed "The quick brown .." in a standard text field, it would be searchable through each word by itself already, so searching for "quick" would give the hit, and highlighting would work out of the box (I don't think you can tell it to highlight the whole sentence, but you could implement that yourself by finding highlighted text and expanding it to the nearest sentence break points). Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I think you are using And operator, to get your desired result you should use OR operator.

Comment: I have a table which contains some data that are indexed. What I want is to search if the **indexed** data is **contained** in the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". Is it possible using solr ?